# Read an AVAudioFile into a buffer starting at a certain time

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioengine, avaudioplayernode, avaudiofile

Let's say I have an AVAudioFile with a duration of 10 seconds. I want to load that file into an AVAudioPCMBuffer but I only want to load the audio frames that come after a certain number of seconds/milliseconds or after a certain AVAudioFramePosition.

It doesn't look like AVAudioFile's *readIntoBuffer* methods give me that kind of precision so I'm assuming I'll have to work at the AVAudioBuffer level or lower?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to set the AVAudioFile's [framePosition](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiofile/1390785-frameposition) property before reading.